# Angular infinite loop

Tags: angular

When I tried to log a component function or service function, it works infinitely. I tried almost all components and pages. Results are same. Sometimes it stops after logged 1000 time and when I clicked, starts infinite loop again. What could I have done wrong?

Is it important performance issue or normal?

any component

```
  testFunction() {
        console.log('test');
    }
```

any html

```
{{testFunction()}}
```

Comment: <!-- Remove the function call from the template -->
<div>Some content</div>

Comment: avoid directly invoking the function in the template using {{}}. Instead, call the function from within the component class at appropriate times.

Comment: Is this normal then? I discovered this as a result of a log I made while trying to find another error.

Comment: HTML-->  [routerLink]="getRouterLink()"

TS--> getRouterLink() {
        if (this.user.isAdmin()) {
            return ['/admin', this.user.getUser.id, 'panel'];
        } else {
            return ['/home'];
        }
    }

when I console.log in this function, again infinite time it works @sai

Answer (score 4):

Its normal that function used in template calls with every change detection cycle. You must have something in your code, that triggers change detection a lot. Maybe some event listener for mouse move, or something like that

Answer (score 2):

It's [generally inadvisable](https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496) to call functions from your template, especially if they do any expensive calculations.

Typically you'd want to set some property on your component (e.g. `currentRouterLink`) when the component is initialized and just have the template refer to the property. The tricky thing is that you need to make sure that property gets updated whenever its value should change. For example, if the logic for your `currentRouterLink` depends on whether the current user is an admin, then you'll probably need to handle events that could change this (like user logins), and change the value accordingly.

If all of the inputs for your expensive logic are cheaply determined, you could put any expensive logic into a pipe that's considered [pure](https://angular.io/api/core/Pipe#pure), and Angular will automatically avoid running the pipe unless its inputs have changed. For more information on this and other workarounds, see [Slow computations](https://angular.io/guide/change-detection-slow-computations) in the Angular guide.

Regardless, it's worth investigating what's causing change detection to run so often. Real problems typically only arise when you have *both* expensive expressions in your template *and* your template re-renders often. So if you can address both issues as a baseline, then you greatly reduce the risk that a small mistake causes big performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

It’s bad practice to invoke a function in your template.

There are many reasons to avoid this approach :

- function is executed every time Angular change detection runs.

So you can enable change strategy to reduce the detectChange in your component :

```
ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
```

The best solution is to use a pure pipe that returns value does not change if your data does not change, it’s based on memoization technique.

Answer (score 1):

you keep routing in a cycle check

- your app.routes has mistake check  your paths
- your authentication guard is keep redirecting you back